# Why my button to go to the next page of API doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript

So I have an API on HTML page, and "next" button to get the next page of API:
[image]

Javascript code for the button:

```
next.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(nextPage <= totalPages){
            pageCall(nextPage);
        } 
    })
```

Code for pageCall function:

```
function pageCall(page){
      let url = new URL(lastUrl)
      url.searchParams.set("page", page)      
      fetchURL(url);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
```

Code for fetchUrl function:

```
function fetchURL(url){
        lastUrl = url;
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
            trendingMovies(data.results);
            currentPage = data.page;
            nextPage = currentPage + 1;
            prevPage = currentPage - 1;
            totalPages = data.total_pages;
            lastPage = totalPages;

            if(currentPage <= 1){
                prev.classList.add('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
            else if(currentPage >= lastPage){
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.add('disabled');
            }else{
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
        })
    }
```

So when I click on next button, the API url changes to page="nextpage" in the end, but suddenly next URL is page="Next", though i don't know where this next comes from.
API URL in console when I click on the button:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key={api_key}&page=2
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&{api_key}&page=Next
```

I get these two URLs when I click on the button, so when I click on it, it always display the first page of API. I have no idea why, cause, as you can see, the page is 2 in the first URL, but suddenly it turns to "next".

Comment: What is `next` if a submit button you need to do `next.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{ e.preventDefault(); ....`

Comment: it must be coming from somewhere. can you add a console.log statement in pageCall() to make sure you are passing in a number? There must be more code somewhere that is sending in that "Next" string.

Comment: @mplungjan hi! i added prevent default, so now instead of page="next" it's just page=

Comment: Please as usual post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I had an event listener for all items, including buttons and numbers, so when you click a number, it called an API page with number value with innerText, so i guess that's why it passed "Next" as innerText too.

So it's my html code of ul:

```
<ul id="pag">
                <li class="btn prev" id="prev"><span><i class="fas fa-angle-left">Prev</i></span></li>
                <li class="numb active" id="numb1"><span>1</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>2</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>3</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>4</span></li>
                <li class="numb" id="numb5"><span>5</span></li>
                <li class="dots"><span>...</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>10</span></li>
                <li class="btn next" id="next"><span>Next<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span></li>
            </ul>
```

As you there're numbers and buttons, and I selected it in javascript code like this:

```
const ulTag = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
```

And it's my function for click event on numbers:

```
function pagination(e) {
        let elems = document.querySelector('.active');
        if (elems !== null) {
          elems.classList.remove('active');
          e.target.classList.toggle('active'); 
          pageCall(e.target.innerText);
        }
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dots')[0];
            let numb1 = document.getElementById('numb1');
            if (parseInt(e.target.innerText) >= 2) {
                numb1.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', dots);
            } 

ulTag.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
            pagination(e);
    }));
```

As you see, it uses the function on all ul elements, so that's the reason page in API was equal to "Next", cause it was button's innerText.
So I corrected it with:

```
const ulTag = document.querySelectorAll('.numb');
```

By selecting only li items with numbers, it solved the problem.

Comment: Good catch, but if you don't update the question to show the portion of code at fault, and show the fix here in your answer, this won't be suitable to maintain on the site. However, if you update question/answer with minimal reproducible examples, it could be a good fit (despite being extremely specific)

Comment: @TCooper thanks, i'll do that!